# Writing VB.Net code for filtering SQL Server table properties

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have several columns in my SQL Server table and want to filter 'Contractor' column. In the 'contractor' column user can choose two names 'Namal' and 'other' as shown in the screenshot.

What I want is to get only sum of 'amount'  for only 'Namal' and not 'other'

Here is the code I have written but not working. Here `@d1` and `@d2` are date ranges which user can be select.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form6
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("server=(local); Database=Luminex; integrated security=true")

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("select sum(Amount) as a  from PeoTVDB where Date between @d1 and @d2 and Contractor= @Namal", connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        command.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        adapter.Fill(table)

        Label1.Text = table.Rows(0)("a").ToString()    

    End Sub        
End Class
```

Comment: You added several irrelevant tags to this question, including C# and MySQL. Please use the correct tags in your future questions.

Comment: You also say _the code i have written but not works_. How doesn't it work? What is the problem you are experiencing. You are not adding the `namal` parameter to your `SqlCommand` either.

Comment: it is very hard to explain my issue but admin allow me to post some screenshots i can explain furthermore

Comment: Paste the links in the comments here and I will put them into your question. Just to clarify, I am not an administrator or moderator

Comment: As someone else mentions, how is the parameter ````@Namal```` getting populated?

Comment: I have found the issue.it is on the sqlcommand. need to change from Contractor=@Namal to Contractor='Namal'  other coding are same. thanks for your kindly supporting...

Answer (score 0):

Keep you database objects local to the method where they are used. If you are using the connection string in several places then place that as a Class level variable.

Database objects need to closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error.

I thought Date might be a reserved word in Sql Server so I escaped it with brackets. Won't hurt anything even if it is not reserved.

I was very glad to see `Parameters` and the `.Add` method. The only problem is you forgot one. I had to guess at the type and what the value is.

Since you are only requesting a single piece of data, you can use `.ExecuteScalar` which returns an object thus the `CDec()`

```
Private ConString As String = "server=(local); Database=Luminex; integrated security=true"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Amount As Decimal
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConString),
        command As New SqlCommand("select COALESCE(sum(Amount), 0) as a  from PeoTVDB where [Date] between @d1 and @d2 and Contractor= @Namal", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        command.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
        command.Parameters.Add("@Namal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = "Some Value"
        connection.Open()
        Amount = CDec(command.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Label1.Text = Amount.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: You should account for the case where ExecuteScalar returns Nothing, e.g. `Dim amount as Decimal` ...other code... `conn.Open()` `Dim result As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` `conn.Close()` `If result IsNot Nothing Then` `amount = CDec(result)` `End If`. If you really want to ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I added COALESCE(sum(Amount), 0) to the select query to handle null. No conn.Close the End Using handles that. Thank you for pointing that out.